# why the div can't "float"?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm very confuses about float. 
.two should be on the right of .one
but .two just below .one

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  background: #FF9;
}
;
 .theone {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="theone">one</div>
<div class="theright">two</div>
```

Comment: I did add float to .theone, just doesn't work.

Comment: .one *is* floating, but .two is a non-floating block, so it can't possibly be on the right of .one.

Answer (score 2):

into div css add display:inline-block;

```
    div{
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     .theright {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

add that in, if you want 2 divs to be next to eachother it is best to have them both float right. 
additionally you could replace .theone with  .theone,.theright

Answer (score 1):

A div has `display: block` by default.

You probably want to set another display type to your divs.

> div {   width: 100px;   background: #FF9;   display: inline; }
>
> .theone {   float: left;   font-size: 20px; }

[See jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85ode941/)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and make a detailled and explained answer. A floating element floats from its initial position in the flow. Basically, the floating effect affects only elements declared *after* it on the HTML structure.

In your case, the right-floating element is declared after the non-floating one. So it is normal `theright` appears below `theone` and you don't see the floating effect.

To make an element float on the right of another, you must declare it *before* this another. Like this :

```
<div class="theright">two</div>
<div class="theone">one</div>
<style>
    .theright {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

Note that for this to work, `theright` element needs to be larger than `theone`. Otherwise, `theone` will mask entirely `theright` pushing its content out of the box. It is so because a floating element gets out of the flow and hovers over the other elements, which contents "avoid" the floating blocks.

There are many other ways to obtain the same result with a different approch :

- make `theone` float on the left instead (leaving `theright` as a basic block element)
- make both elements inline-blocks and give them appropriate widths
- for two elements only, it is not necessary, but if you need 3 or more elements side by side, you can make them all float on the left (or on the right declaring them in reverse order, depending on the final layout you want)
- etc.

Comment: By the way, OP has width: 100px not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  background: #FF9;
display: inline-block;
}
;
 .theone {
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="theone">one</div>
<div class="theright">two</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

By default div's have display value set to "block" which means they "begin from next line". 
If you add display: inline-block property for all divs, then you can add float: left for any div to make it first.

Comment: An element doesn't need to be `ìnline-block` to float... You're mixing different things.